# Is it possible to use registerForAutoconfiguration inside CompilerPass?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying to simplify my applications dependency injection by creating a base injection class.
So far most of the code works fine, except for `registerForAutoconfiguration`

Here is the relevant code:

```
abstract class AbstractTaggedPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    protected $interfaceClass;
    protected $serviceClass;
    protected $tag;
    protected $method;

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // always first check if the primary service is defined
        if (!$container->has($this->serviceClass)) {
            return;
        }

        // Register classes implementing the interface with tag
        $container->registerForAutoconfiguration($this->interfaceClass)->addTag($this->tag); // Does not work

        $definition = $container->findDefinition($this->serviceClass);

        // find all service IDs with the tag
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds($this->tag);

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $attributes) {
                $definition->addMethodCall($this->method, [new Reference($id)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class SubscriptionPaymentProviderPass extends AbstractTaggedPass
{
    protected $interfaceClass = SubscriptionPaymentProviderInterface::class
    protected $serviceClass = SubscriptionPaymentProviderPool::class;
    protected $tag = 'subscription.payment_provider';
    protected $method = 'addProvider';
}
```

```
class SubscriptionBundle extends Bundle
{
    protected function getContainerExtensionClass()
    {
        return SubscriptionExtension::class;
    }

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        //$container->registerForAutoconfiguration(SubscriptionPaymentProviderInterface::class)->addTag('subscription.payment_provider');
        $container->addCompilerPass(new SubscriptionPaymentProviderPass());
    }
}
```

If I move `registerForAutoconfiguration` line from Bundle class into the CompilerPass class, then it no longer registers Services with the correct tag.

Is it possible to use it inside a compiler pass?
Do I need to enable something to make it work?

Comment: Have you considered using `_instanceof:` to tag your services, e.g. `SubscriptionPaymentProviderInterface`, and then pass them as arguments to the `SubscriptionPaymentProviderPool` using `!tagged_iterator`? See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services

Comment: If I remember correctly _instanceof and _defaults works only for services defined inside the same bundle (correct me if I am wrong). My use case is different, I have a feature+plugins system, where feature is defined in one bundle and then each plugin is defined as separate bundle. So in example i showed here I have a feature subscription-bundle and then plugins for payment methods like credit-card-subscription-bundle, paypal-subscription-bundle, someotherbank-subscription-bundle etc. I am using the AbstractTaggedPass to inject installed plugins into the feature.

Comment: You are right, only classes that are defined in the same service config-file will be used, which is usually fine for applications, but will not work in a bundle/plugin system-context. For this CompilerPass is the right solution. I will have a closer look then

Answer (score 3):

Compiler Pass is used *after* service definitions are parsed (via configuration file or extensions).
I think the right place for do this, is into an [Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class).